# Android - CaptioningManager class

Tags: android, casting, google-cast, caption

In CastCompanionLibrary, which I use in my application, there is a part of code, which looks like this:

```
CaptioningManager captioningManager = (CaptioningManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);
return captioningManager.isEnabled();
```

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager.html) for `CaptioningManager` class is very brief and I do not know why method `isEnabled()` returns different values (`true` or `false`) on various devices.

Does anybody know, what determines the returned value or how can I change this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns true if at the system level user has enabled captions (Settings -> Accessibility -> Captions), false other wise.

CCL, for versions of android that do have that settings in the framework, honors that settings and uses that for styling tracks. For earlier versions of Android, it offers a preference page that provides the same set of options.

Answer (score 0):

We have the next statement in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager.java/?v=source):

```
/**
 * @return the user's preferred captioning enabled state
 */
public final boolean isEnabled() {
    return Secure.getInt(
            mContentResolver, Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_CAPTIONING_ENABLED, DEFAULT_ENABLED) == 1;
}
```

So, the value depends on a user's accessibility settings. I'm not sure but looks like it is settings to show subtitles by default or not.